# Why is Header longer than its containing block if its in percentage

Tags: html, css

My header (#M_header UL) is wider than its containing block(#M_header) even though it is set at 100% width. I just recently started using % for the width over PX, so I am new to it.

code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header id = "M_head">
                <h2><ul>Title</ul></h2> 
            </header>

            <nav id="M_nav">
                <ul>
                    <a href=""><li>MUSIC</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li>NEWS</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li>STORE</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li>BLOG</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li>CONTACTS</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li>ABOUT</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <section id="M_section">
                <div id="M_stuff"></div>
            </section>
            <footer id="M_footer">

            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    font-size:1em;
    display:block;
}


#container {
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;  
    margin: 0px auto;
    border:2px solid black;
    width:75%;
}

#M_head {
    color:black;
    border:2px solid blue;
    width:100%;
}

#M_head ul {
    text-align:left;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
```

js.fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/65taytw6/

Comment: why `<ul>` here `<h2><ul>Title</ul></h2>`? no need for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added padding value as 0.check the below site.

```
#M_head ul {
    text-align:left;
    border:2px solid blue;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65taytw6/2/

Comment: Is there by any chance a default padding on the ul?

Comment: yes not all elements in html.only some elements like ul is having default padding or margin else both.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to UL to take the same width as container.
No need to specify the width of UL.

Just make the following change in your css file. Remove width property.

```
#M_head ul {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    text-align: left;
    /* width: 100%; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65taytw6/1/)

```
#M_head ul {
    text-align:left;
    border:2px solid blue;
    width:inherit;
}
```

make width to inherit

Answer (score 1):

For better solution use `*{margin:0; padding:0;}`
Wherever you want just apply margin or padding as per your requirement, it will reset all HTML tags margin and padding.